# How to get 'No User found' message from the below variable in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js

How to get 'No User found' message from the below variable in Node.js

```
{"error":["No User found."]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var data = {"error":["No User found."]};

alert(data.error[0]);
```

The outer object has a property `"error"`.  That property, then contains an array from which you want the first element in the array (index `0`).

So, you get the `error` property with `data.error`.  And, then you reach into the array and get the first element with `data.error[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through this object with a for loop and grab the value based on the name of the property.

```
for(item in obj){
console.log(obj[item]);
}
```

You can use an if statement and the match method if you need to make sure that the property name is 'error'.

Here is my fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nhmaggiej/eajqzxfr/